# wamp httpd virtual host embedded pdf and other files, not displaying only shows download

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp, httpd.conf

I was using laravel built in server and all the embedded files and pdf are displayed well

but when I try to test it on wamp server using virtual host the files that are embedded are no longer being displayed it only prompt to download the file, both in chrome and Mozilla

I think I miss-configured something in in httpd where I just add the code below to my httpd-vhost.conf, please help, thanks in advance

```
<Directory "C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/projects">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\projects\public_html"
    ServerName www.laravel-site.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You are a bit short on useful information. Does the vhost work i.e. are you using `www.laravel-site.dev` in the browser url? It would be a good idea to make the `<Directory...` specify the same path as the `DocumentRoot`. Also I would stick with the UNIX forward slash everywhere rather than the DOS backslash.

Comment: yes sir everything works well only the problem is it doesn't display the embedded files, anyway I don't know how i fix this, but after a day of reading and playing around on Apache out of nowhere it just displayed the embedded PDF, maybe i change the "order allow,deny allow from all" to "Require all granted" and also change the dos backslash to unix forward slash

Answer (score 1):

.htacess
This will allow some files that exist to be displayed directly you can edit by changing the extensions on line 2.

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: thankz for the info. but I know now what was causing the problem, its when I put my wamp to online mode, my internet download manager-IDM  automatically captures files from my domain name, i add the domain name to IDM address exception list and it ok now.

Comment: Glad you could sort it out :)